# Python says my variable is not defined but I defined it correctly in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if firplay == "HB gut":
        import random
        _1 = "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN"
        _2 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _3 = "Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!"
        _4 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _5 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _6 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _7 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _8 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _9 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"
        _10 = "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"

        PossibleOutcomes = [_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10]
        mychoice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
        print(mychoice)  
        if "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == mychoice:
            print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

        elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" == mychoice:
            _2play = input ("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Stop and go, or Hook and ladder?")

        else:
            print("You would be a horrible head coach your team will never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")

        if _2play == "Bubble catch":
            import random
```

Comment: There is no loop here. If you mean the `_2play = input...` inside `elif`, it will be defined only in that one case. If `mychoice` is anything else, it will not be defined when it is used, and will raise an exception. As an aside - every time you are tempted to make variables like `_1`, `_2`..., you would be better off using a data structure, such as a `list`.

Comment: We can't see where firplay is defined, it only appears once in your code.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the code, there are a few items.

1. Probably better if you just put the _* strings into a list directly,as
   in:

   PossibleChoices = ["Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN", ...]
2. Then it'd be mychoice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
3. You'd probably then just compare mychoice with PossibleOutcomes[0].
4. With:
   `
   if "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN" == mychoice:
   print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")

   ```
    elif "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16" == mychoice:
        _2play = input ("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Stop and go, or Hook and ladder?")

    else:
        print("You would be a horrible head coach your team will never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")

    if _2play == "Bubble catch":
        import random`
   ```

4a) You don't need to do a `import random` again.
4b) `_2play` isn't defined anywhere aside for in the 2nd condition, so if the user 'wins', the `if _2play == "Bubble catch"` is run, and since _2play isn't defined there, it'll error.  Since _2play is irrelevant with the first and third conditions, you can just catch the _2play variable in the 2nd condition.

So a cleaned up code could be:

```
if firplay == "HB gut":
    import random

    PossibleOutcomes = [
        "Yay you scored a 97 yard touchdown. This scenario is over. YOU WIN",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "Your team commited a turnover. This scenario is over. YOU LOSE!",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16",
        "You Gained 3 yards now it is 2nd and 7 from your own 16"]

        mychoice = random.choice(PossibleOutcomes)
        print(mychoice)  
        if mychoice == PossibleOutcomes[0]:
            print ("You would be an amazing head coach and luck will always be on your side")
        elif mychoice == PossibleOutcomes[1]:
            _2play = input ("It's your ball on the Seattle 16. The defense is in cover 2. What play do you want to run? Bubble catch, Stop and go, or Hook and ladder?")
            if _2play == "Bubble catch":
                ...
        else:
            print("You would be a horrible head coach your team will never make the playoffs and you will be fired.")

          ...
```

Of course, it could be further cleaned up.  The above is just something that could solve your problem.